# Adding a sub item based on time

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a sorted list of events for a location: `List<PlannedEvent> PlannedEvents`

Let's then say that each event looks like this:

```
public class PlannedEvent
{
    public string EventName {get; set;}
    public List<string> Attendees {get; set;}
    public DateTime StartTime {get; set;}
}
```

Now, since I'm holding all events at a discrete location, I know that only one event can occur at a time.

Random guy 'Bob' comes along and he doesn't know his event name (silly Bob).
But, he does know when he's going to arrive - which is sometime during the event.

What is a good way to find out which event 'Bob' will be attending?

I'd rather not iterate through the `List<PlannedEvent>` one by one,

Is there a better way?

(Note: This contrived problem, and its assumptions, is very similar to my actual problem, with the benefit of being very easy to understand. It is not my problem exactly)

Comment: 'Bob' must be in the `Attendees` list, right ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I need to add him to the Attendees list; he's registering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing the question I came up with the following solution:

`PlannedEvents.Last(pe => pe.StartTime <= BobArrivalTime)`

Comment: presuming `PlannedEvents` are sorted.